# Parsing JSON data entries for specific field values

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm currently trying to parse the following JSON file via its entries for the following fields but have been having issues trying to iterate through the file to do so. Could somebody possibly help me find an efficient way to figure this out?

```
import requests
import json

jsonFile = open("/users/bboyf/Downloads/Aaron697_Brekke496_2fa15bc7-8866-461a-9000-f739e425860a.json", "r")
data = json.load(jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()

idValue = data['entry'][223]['resource']['medicationCodeableConcept']['coding'][0]['code']

print(idValue)

r = requests.get('https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/interaction/list.json?rxcuis='+ idValue)

print(r.text)
```

More specifically I'm trying to figure out a way to find idValues if there are multiple ones in the many entries that are stored in the json data file. Is there an effective way to better obtain these values by parsing the file or going through a for loop in the entries?

```
idValue = data['entry'][223]['resource']['medicationCodeableConcept']['coding'][0]['code']
```

Also how would you iterate the data which has the following data hiearchy?
https://jsonblob.com/f92fabd6-db8b-11eb-bf92-87c0d3acf4df

Comment: can you share the JSON schema? sure to see all you need to loop, and please explain better what you have and your expected output as a sample. from where to where. :) thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you can access the JSON file here, which better provides the schema.

Comment: https://jsonblob.com/f92fabd6-db8b-11eb-bf92-87c0d3acf4df

Comment: My expected output is to return the code field which is stored under the subfield of 'medicationCodeableConcept'

Comment: There isn't really anything better than looping through the data after parsing.

Comment: How exactly would we loop through the data after parsing? Like for instance looping through each entry and checking to see if it has the field medicationCodeableConcept?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution.

```
import json

# conver string to JSON
f = open("./file.json",)

# returns JSON object as 
# dictionary
data = json.load(f)

# Iterate through the json
# list

for obj in data["entry"]:
    if "medicationCodeableConcept" in obj["resource"]:
        for codes in obj["resource"]["medicationCodeableConcept"]["coding"]:
            print("system: {} \ncode: {} \ndisplay: {}".format(codes['system'], codes['code'], codes['display']))

f.close()
```